# Which Stack Exchange Q&A site should I use to ask questions related to university admissions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, stack-exchange

I wanted to ask a few questions regarding the universities I'm interested in. 
So which Stack Exchange Q&A community should I be using for this?

I have visited [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) and I felt that it is more of a Q&A site for college students. 
So is there a Stack Exchange platform dedicated only for *university admissions* and stuff?

Comment: If you are interested in undergraduate admissions, there is no appropriate SE site. I know a former SE employee now works for https://www.collegeconfidential.com/ - I haven't used the site and have no idea how question-asking works there (I think that part of the site is more like a forum than Q&A site).

Comment: As @BryanKrause mentioned, College Confidential is a forum for university admissions with a focus on high school students entering 4-year colleges and universities. (Disclosure: I'm a community manager for that site.) As with most online communities, we ask that people read before they post to make sure their question hasn't already been asked. But we do allow very personal questions, including asking about chances of getting in based on SAT/ACT/GPA. (Though this year the test scores are not always considered by schools.) There are also forums for specific schools, which you might appreciate.

Comment: @JonEricson For redirecting people in the future, especially those that land on Academia.SE... does your site mostly focus on the US? or US and Europe? or are you more comprehensively international in scope? (and what about language, too: English only or are other languages supported?)

Comment: @BryanKrause: It's almost entirely US schools. That means students from other countries are welcome, but the discussions are in English and there's not much information about universities in Europe or the UK. (I'd like to expand the topics, but that depends on finding people who want to talk about other situations. It's a chicken and egg problem.)

Comment: @JonEricson Do you filter at all by tier of school? is TRACS, for example, included? (I ask because there was someone recently asking at Academia.SE whether their TRACS degree meant anything).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) seems the only site you are looking for. It has a dedicated tag for [graduate-admissions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/graduate-admissions/info). Its tag wiki excerpt says that the tag is to be used for questions:

> On strategies, procedures, and problems related to getting admitted to, or selecting students to be admitted to, a graduate degree program.

However, if you have a question regarding undergraduate admission, Academia is not suitable as such questions are [off-topic there](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 6):

Not all sorts of questions have an appropriate SE site to ask on.

Since you are asking about "questions **regarding the universities** I'm interested in", even for graduate admissions this would likely be off-topic at Academia.SE as a ["shopping question"](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3657/why-was-my-question-put-on-hold-for-shopping).

Undergraduate admissions are even more [clearly off-topic](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) there.

More general questions about graduate admissions are on-topic.